# Webpack: Regex in html filename?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

My filename in url is something like:

```
index.qwe123.html
```

Where *qwe123* is a random string. I want to display index.html file regardless this string. How do I customize in Webpack config:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, SOURCE_ROOT + '/static/index.html')
        })
```

So, this index.html would be served regardless of the dynamic part.

Comment: Can "path.resolve(__dirname, SOURCE_ROOT + '/static/index.html')" accept RegEx?

Comment: I wonder if [How to use HtmlWebpackPlugin for multiple files with wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47603174/1563833) is helpful to you?

Comment: @Wyck got some idea. Thanks!